# Dota 2 wins being counted as losses

Tags: steam, dota-2

Last night I won about 4 games on Dota 2. The games were completely unbalanced to our side and I "trolled" a bit, but nothing special.

All of the games were added to my loss counter rather than my wins. Does anyone know why it is happening?

Comment: if you go watch->recent games->filter your own games, do they still show up as losses when you click the details button?

Answer (score 1):

It seems a bug. If your game history, as suggested by @yx in comments, registered the matches as **wins** for your team, submit the bug to Dota 2 Beta [dev forum](http://dev.dota2.com). Copy down the IDs of your matches to let the devs check easier what went wrong.

Comment: I've tried to access the dev forum many times and it will not allow me to sign into it even though I created an account.